# Windows update 1909 can't be installed. Goes through the process, reboots and nothing happened. No error

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10-v1909

I tried to install the 1909 update since there are messages that my current version  1803 will be out of support.

It doesn't work with Windows Update nor with the Windows 10 Update-Assistent.

I've tried the top 40 google results but none of them works.

SetupDiag doesn't come with an error as far as I can see (last action is a success).

After the 2nd reboot I've must enter the bitlocker recovery key to continue.

Comment: *"It doesn't work*" - It might be helpful to [edit] your question and give details about the steps you're taking and what happens afterwards (how you know it didn't update after reboot, etc).

Comment: In the C:\Windows.BT folder, there's a setuplog.txt file or whatever the file is called. This will tell you exactly what's happening.

Comment: The setup logs doesn't say anything about why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the only working solution was to download the latest windows 10 iso (1909). ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10))
Mount the iso and start the setup / update using that format.

The Windows Update and Windows 10 Update Assistent did't work.